# What are these thing in my fridge and how to get ride of them?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, refrigerator, insect

I found these bugs and i dont know how to get ride of them or what they are.

[image]

First time it was near the eggs, cleaned everything. But 3 weekd after i found them again. Dont know what to do.

If this is not the proper stackexchange site for this post feel free to move it. Sorry

Comment: Although your home would surely be improved by removing these, this isn't a "Home Improvement" topic. Try [http://biology.stackexchange.com/]. (And, when you do, post a close-up picture of one of the blotches.)

Comment: Thanks! But i dont know how to move my post

Comment: I don't, either. Check the help section, but the easiest thing would be to re-post it yourself and let this get deleted (especially as you need to do some editing, e.g. that closeup picture).